# Where could I find the code for the 'div' re-sizing of the site below (is there a name for the style)?

Tags: html, css

I am interested in learning how the 'divs' re-size up to a point then change their display mode and restart the re-sizing.

This is the site:

> http://www.wnyc.org/

Comment: It's known as responsive template. [Check this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is using @media to change the size according to the screen size, if you want to try something like that you can research about media queries and viewports(viewport units)